# React: Passing two onclick functions in functional component

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass two functions to a button when it's clicked. The first changes the state of component to true, and after that it performs the second function. When I used class components, this was the syntax to perform a follow-up function after setting state, but it doesn't work with functional components. Now when I add a second function, none of them work. Is there a different syntax?

```
<button onClick={() => setStart(true), () => {countMiliseconds()}}>Start</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create `useEffect` hook that will be run after state changed to true

---

```
    useEffect(() =>{ start && countMilliseconds() }, [ start ])
```

---

Assuming start set to `false` at initial render

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to react to `start` state changes:

```
function MyAwesomeComponent() {
  const [start, setStart] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => start && countMiliseconds(), [start]);

  return <button onClick = {
    () => setStart(true)
  } > Start < /button>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do like this i suppose

```
<button

onClick={()=> {
  setStart(true);
  countMiliseconds();
}}

Start
</button>
```